# Ask questions about Android VTS

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-vts

I ask questions about Android VTS.

I am currently working on ubuntu 18.04, and target device is working on AVD.
First of all, the environment I set is as follows.

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip fontconfig

$ mkdir android && cd android
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-11.0.0_r28
$ repo sync -c  -j $(($(nproc) - 2)) --no-tags --no-clone-bundle           
$ repo start android-11.0.0_r28 --all   


$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebug
$ m
```

I have successfully built and confirmed that the emulator works well.

```
$ emulator -no-window -writable-system
$ adb root remount
$ adb device
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

After that, I built the following vts to analyze the behavior of Android keymaster.

```
$ cd hardware\interfaces\keymaster\3.0\vts\functional
$ mm
```

After successful module build, I ran the emulator and pushed the binary as follows.

```
$ emulator -no-window -writable-system
$ adb root remount
$ adb push out\soong\.intermediates\hardware\interfaces\keymaster\3.0\vts\functional\VtsHalKeymasterV3_0TargetTest\android_x86_64\VtsHalKeymasterV3_0TargetTest /data/tmp
```

I did the above successfully, and I ran the binary and it looks like this:

```
$ adb shell /data/tmp/VtsHalKeymasterV3_0TargetTest

[==========] Running 12 tests from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 12 tests from GoogleTestVerification
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<KeymasterVersionTest>
Paramaterized test suite KeymasterVersionTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<KeymasterVersionTest> (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<NewKeyGenerationTest>
Paramaterized test suite NewKeyGenerationTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<NewKeyGenerationTest> (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<GetKeyCharacteristicsTest>
Paramaterized test suite GetKeyCharacteristicsTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<GetKeyCharacteristicsTest> (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<SigningOperationsTest>
Paramaterized test suite SigningOperationsTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<SigningOperationsTest> (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<VerificationOperationsTest>
Paramaterized test suite VerificationOperationsTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<VerificationOperationsTest> (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<ExportKeyTest>
Paramaterized test suite ExportKeyTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<ExportKeyTest> (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<ImportKeyTest>
Paramaterized test suite ImportKeyTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<ImportKeyTest> (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<EncryptionOperationsTest>
Paramaterized test suite EncryptionOperationsTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<EncryptionOperationsTest> (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<MaxOperationsTest>
Paramaterized test suite MaxOperationsTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<MaxOperationsTest> (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<AddEntropyTest>
Paramaterized test suite AddEntropyTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<AddEntropyTest> (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<AttestationTest>
Paramaterized test suite AttestationTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<AttestationTest> (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<KeyDeletionTest>
Paramaterized test suite KeyDeletionTest is defined via TEST_P, but never instantiated. None of the test cases will run. Either no INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P is provided or the only ones provided expand to nothing.

Ideally, TEST_P definitions should only ever be included as part of binaries that intend to use them. (As opposed to, for example, being placed in a library that may be linked in to get other utilities.)
[       OK ] GoogleTestVerification.UninstantiatedParamaterizedTestSuite<KeyDeletionTest> (0 ms)
[----------] 12 tests from GoogleTestVerification (2 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 12 tests from 1 test suite ran. (3 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 12 tests.
```

It only took 3ms to complete the following.
When I check it closely, the test itself does not seem to proceed.
I have not made any additional changes to the source or other details.
Anyone who knows what else I need to do to run the keymaster vts would be appreciated.

Comment: What is Android VTS?

Comment: I don't have much experience with Android, so I can't explain in detail, but roughly I think it's a functional test.
For more details, please refer to the link below.
https://source.android.com/compatibility/vts